# Can't compile libpqxx 6 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, postgresql, compiler-errors, libpqxx

I'm trying to compile the example code for the postgres C++ drivers libpqxx 6 [repo here](https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx). I keep getting errors (as below). Anyone know how to resolve ?

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I /usr/local/include/pqxx/ -L /usr/local/lib/ -I 
/usr/local/pgsql/include/ -L 
/usr/local/pgsql/lib/ postgres.cpp -lpqxx  -lpq
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/functional:55:0,
         from /usr/include/c++/5/memory:79,
         from /usr/local/include/pqxx/binarystring.hxx:17,
         from /usr/local/include/pqxx/binarystring:10,
         from /usr/local/include/pqxx/pqxx:10,
         from postgres.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/tuple:991:33: error: ‘array’ was not declared in this scope
 struct __is_tuple_like_impl<array<_Tp, _Nm>> : true_type
                         ^
/usr/include/c++/5/tuple:991:44: error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)
 struct __is_tuple_like_impl<array<_Tp, _Nm>> : true_type
                                    ^
/usr/include/c++/5/tuple:979:12: note: provided for ‘template<class> 
struct std::__is_tuple_like_impl’
 struct __is_tuple_like_impl : false_type
    ^
/usr/include/c++/5/tuple:991:47: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘>’ token
 struct __is_tuple_like_impl<array<_Tp, _Nm>> : true_type
                                       ^
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'postgres' failed
make: *** [postgres] Error 1
```

Comment: If array isn't being found #include <array>

Comment: @SoronelHaetir , thanks I missed that for some reason !